# Does CMOS reset, Factoy reset data

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot

Does removing and reinserting the CMOS reset all the data present in a laptop?

I want to dual boot Kali Linux with Windows 10 but I couldn't get to the BIOS settings.

I surfed the net, and it said to reset the CMOS.

Comment: I find your question ambiguous, what is your problem: you can't get Windows and Linux to dual boot or you can't get into the BIOS settings?

Answer (score 2):

No, will force to load the default configuration of the B.I.O.S setup, can be done with removing the battery temporaly or just choosing the "load default settings" option inside the bios setup. The data inside the HDD/SDD will be fine.

Comment: It helped So Now I am good to go

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the CMOS (aka BIOS) will only reset the settings inside the BIOS, not wipe your harddrive. They are the settings for your harddrive connection, cdrom, time/date and that kind of thing. If you never altered your BIOS settings, resetting them to factory should not make any important change.

But keep in mind, if you have changed the setting for SATA to support an onboard RAID controller, it is likely resetting this back to IDE. Although it will work, it will likely give weird results. So check on that bit right after the CMOS reset.